# What is the difference between "perl -n" and "perl -p"?

Tags: perl

What is the difference between the `perl -n` and `perl -p` options?

What is a simple example to demonstrate the difference?

How do you decide which one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between the perl -n and perl -p options?

`-p` causes each line to be printed; equivalent to:

```
    while (<>) { ... } continue { print }
```

`-n` does not automatically print each line; equivalent to:

```
    while(<>) {...}
```

---

> What is a simple example to demonstrate the difference?

e.g., replace `foo` with `FOO`:

```
$ echo 'foo bar' | perl -pe 's/foo/FOO/'
FOO bar
$ echo 'foo bar' | perl -ne 's/foo/FOO/'
$
```

---

> How do you decide which one to use?

One example where `-n` is useful is when you don't want every line printed, and there is a conditional print in the code, e.g., only show lines containing `foo`:

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar\nanother foo' | perl -ne 'print if /foo/;'
foo
another foo
$
```

The command-line options are documented in [perlrun documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun)

Answer (score 10):

> How do you decide which one to use?

You use `-p` if you want to automatically print the contents of `$_` at the end of each iteration of the implied `while` loop. You use `-n` if you don't want to print `$_` automatically.

An example of `-p`. Adding line numbers to a file:

```
$ perl -pe '$_ = "$.: $_"' your_file.txt
```

An example of `-n`. A basic `grep` replacement.

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /some search text/' your_file.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

`-p` is short for `-np`, and it causes `$_` to be printed for each pass of the loop created by `-n`.

---

```
perl -ne'...'
```

executes the following program:

```
LINE: while (<>) {
    ...
}
```

while

```
perl -pe'...'
```

executes the following program:

```
LINE: while (<>) {
    ...
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

---

See [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for documentation about `perl`'s command-line options.

Comment: What do you mean by *`-p` is short for `-np`*?  I don't see that in the documentation.

Comment: The docs describe `-p` differently than I did, but equivalently. My description more accurately reflects the implementation and acknowledges the similarity between the two, while perlrun pretends they're completely different and unrelated. But again, both explanations, while different, are equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

perl -n is equivalent to while(<>){...}
perl -p is equivalent to while(<>){...;print;}

Comment: Same as @Rob Bednark's answer : With `-p`, the print is in a `continue` block. You can test it easily by running the following command : `perl -pe 'next'`, and see that it prints whatever you enter, whereas `while(<>) {next;print;}` wouldn't print anything.